# Customer relationship management software for stores and supermarkets

Tags: crm

I was wondering what customer relationship management software exists for Android, designed specifically for stores and supermarkets (for managers and staff).

I am looking for a software that allows store managers to keep track of what customers have said to them (even sharing and importing chats from customers, from messaging apps, or from jotted down conversations in Google keep, to the software system). The system should also interface with what they have bought (importing from smart shopping list or product reader machines that record customer purchase information transmitted via card and fidelity card, for instance, so that the system remembers all the product list purchased and can also present it to managers and staff members, who may annotate the purchase, for their own needs, or for relationships with customers and suppliers, or, by the customer, via a special app, at a later time (as they may want to view what they have bought and how much they have paid for each item, thus keeping track of all receipts (and also being able to transmit these receipts electronically, where needed)).

What such software systems are available on Android?

Thanks.